# Maps version V1 is crashing in Android 10

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am using map version V1 in my android app. It's working fine till Android Pie(9) but it's crashing in Android 10.
I am getting below exception

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;
    at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(MapActivity.java:356)
```

I have already tried below code in android manifest file

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

and below code in my gradle file

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added the Apache HTTP Legacy declaration within the `<application>` element, i.e.:

```
<application ...>

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

<application/>
```

If you're using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0` or above then you don't need to add this at all. Refer to Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library).

I just created a map activity project targeting Android 10 (API level 29) and it ran without problem for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This works on Android 9 but still crashes the MapView on Android 10 (even though my own HttpClient use works on 10). I've added the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0` dependency and the org.apache.http.legacy entries to both build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml. For the code to compile, I have to use `compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:24"` and not just 24. I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Can you please post your code, build.gradle and manifest file? If you create a brand new project targeting Android 10 does it still crash or are you able to load the map with your API key?

Comment: evan, are you sure you are talking about version 1 of the API ?

Comment: Actually you're right, I was not! Was referring to V2 sorry. Will look into it.

Comment: Can you please share a link to your Maps SDK for Android V1 code, so that I can reproduce this from my side? Note that V1 was deprecated in 2013 so it's almost a miracle that it still works at all (in Android 9)!