# Android 10: Google Maps v1 crashing

Tags: android, google-maps, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

Google Maps v1 is not working on Android 10. Getting the following crash:

```
Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 12516
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;
    at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(MapActivity.java:356)
    at com.xxx.view.MapMenuActivity.<init>(MapMenuActivity.java:34)
    at com.xxx.view.branches.BranchesMapActivity.<init>(BranchesMapActivity.java:28)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
    at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(MapActivity.java:356) 
    at com.xxx.view.MapMenuActivity.<init>(MapMenuActivity.java:34) 
    at com.xxx.view.branches.BranchesMapActivity.<init>(BranchesMapActivity.java:28) 
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) 
    at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

gradle file includes the following dependencies and configs:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionName '4.1'
        versionCode 701   
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    implementation files('libs/maps.jar')

    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'gradle/wrapper', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11'
}
```

I have already added the following which makes it work till Android 9.0

```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

I have looked into [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:failed resolution of :Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461881/java-lang-noclassdeffounderrorfailed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-http-protocolve), [HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio), [Google maps v1 crashing in android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028211/google-maps-v1-crashing-in-android-10)
But these resources are working fine for Android 9.0, not for Android 10

Is there any solution to make Android 10 work with Google Maps v1?

Comment: Why in the world are you still using v1 of maps? That was deprecated several years ago?

Comment: @tyczj It is a very old app still in production. We are upgrading the app and set to release soon. However, for the time being, we need the older one to work.

Comment: I'm in this exact situation as well @Nav

Comment: Need help on this too

Comment: @Nav, I am too in a similar situation, have you found any solution for the same ?